# filter ng-repeat through input with ng-model on ng-submit

Tags: angularjs

I'm sure this isn't hard too do but if anyone can help me out.

[here is a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/34PHgyfVsCRsfUSeMSO0?p=preview)

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
  <input ng-model="query">
  <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >Search</button>
</form>


<div ng-repeat="x in friends | filter:query">
  {{x.name}}
</div>
```

i want to filter a search on submission rather than dynamic typing I'm guessing it can be with done with either ng-click or ng-submit. just after a nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code, see the output below.

First you need to set another variable on scope and filter by that variable, on submit() make the "query" model's value be equal to "q" variable on scope, that will filter it accordingly as filtering criteria is "q" now

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.q="";
    
    $scope.submit=function(){
      $scope.q= $scope.query
    }
    $scope.friends = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Sarah"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Joanna"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Heather"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Kim"
    }
    ];
    

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.7"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input ng-model="query">
    <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Search</button>
  </form>


  <div ng-repeat="x in friends | filter:q">
    {{x.name}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sweet! i like this way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: my pleasure, glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with Angular.js 1.3.x using ng-model-options...

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
  <input ng-model="query" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }">
  <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >Search</button>
</form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9JHnSXAldpm7Yb9Bl2gC?p=preview

It lets you customize a delay rather then doing it immediately as you type but it's not on submit.